# viewing global variable in mulitthreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a gui with buttons to start a loop and another button to stop the loop. I use a global variable - run for the loop. 1 to loop and 0 to stop loop. Below is the code I am using.

```
import pygtk
pygtk require('2.0')
import gtk
import threading
import time

run = 0
mythread = ""

class daqGui:
    def start_program(self):
        global run
        print ("start program")
        i = 0
        while run:
            print ("Count = %s\n" % i)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(2)

    def start_run(self, widget):
        global run
        global mythread
        run = 1
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_program, args=())
        mythread.start()

    def stop_run:
        global run
        print("Halt loop")
        run = 0

     def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        self.window.set_size_request(600,400)

        table = gtk.Table(10, 6, True)
        self.window.add(table)

        run_button = gtk.Button("Start Run")
        run_button.connect("clicked", self.start_run)
        run_button.set_size_request(100,30)
        table.attach(run_button, 0, 1, 0, 1, False, False, xpadding=0, ypaddig=0)
        run_button.show()

        stop_button = gtk.Button("Halt Run")
        stop_button.connect("clicked", self.stop_run)
        stop_button.set_size_request(100,30)
        table.attach(stop_button, 2, 3, 0, 1, False, False, xpadding=0, ypaddig=0)
        stop_button.show()

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__=="__main__":
    daqGui()
    main()
```

What happens when you run this code, click on the Start Button,  you will see the program display i = 1, i = 2 and so forth. Click on the stop button, the program does not stop. Exit the gui, and the loop still continues. You have to kill the process to stop it. What am I doing wrong??   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are sketchy with multithreaded code, and especially with a GUI.

The following code starts a "clock" thread which outputs the time every second.

After two seconds, a 2nd thread sets the `stop_event` flag, which is shared between both threads.

When the clock thread checks the event object, it sees that it's been flagged, so the loop exits.  Generally, the event hasn't been set, so it waits for 1.0 seconds then reruns the loop.

### source

```
import threading, time

def display_clock(event):
    while not event.wait(1):
        print 'now:',time.strftime('%X')
    print("stop_event set")

def stop_clock(event):
    time.sleep(3)
    event.set()

def main():
    stop_event = threading.Event()

    threading.Thread(
        target=display_clock, args=[stop_event],
    ).start()

    threading.Thread(
        target=stop_clock, args=[stop_event],
    ).start()

    # wait for all threads to die
    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th != threading.current_thread():
            th.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### output

```
now: 15:17:16
now: 15:17:17
now: 15:17:18
stop_event set
```